# Setting IActiveView extent?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I'm having a problem when setting the IactivewViews extent. I have done it the same way on other places and it does work. In here, it just throws me a LoaderLockException.

```
        // OLD CODE
        private void airspaceElementsTreeView_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.Name.StartsWith("feature_"))
            {
                IFeatureWorkspace workspace = ((IDataset)_LoadedAirspace.UnderlyingObject.Table).Workspace as IFeatureWorkspace;
                ITable relatedTable = workspace.OpenTable(e.Node.Parent.Name);

                int oid = GetNodeObjectId(e.Node);
                IRow tempRow = relatedTable.GetRow(oid);

                IGeometry geom = null;

                if (tempRow is IFeature)
                {
                    IFeature feat = tempRow as IFeature;

                    geom = feat.ShapeCopy;
                    ISpatialReference srCopy = ((IClone)geom.SpatialReference).Clone() as ISpatialReference;

                    IEnvelope envelope = new EnvelopeClass();
                    envelope.SpatialReference = srCopy;
                    envelope.Union(geom.Envelope);
                    envelope.Expand(.25, .25, false);

                    // error here!
                    IActiveView view = ((IMxDocument)m_application.Document).ActiveView;
                    view.Extent = envelope;
                }
                else
                    return;

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(relatedTable);
            }
            else
                return;
        }
```

By the way, this is inside a IDockableWindowDef. Any chance that THAT is ruining things for me?

**edit** following the suggestions of my fellow friends, I did on two separate statements. First I'm trying to get IMxDocument from m_application and then casting it to IActiveView.

It crashes when I'm trying to cast m_application.Document to IMxDocument (check new code below)

```
    private void airspaceElementsTreeView_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Name.StartsWith("feature_"))
        {
            IFeatureWorkspace workspace = ((IDataset)_LoadedAirspace.UnderlyingObject.Table).Workspace as IFeatureWorkspace;
            ITable relatedTable = workspace.OpenTable(e.Node.Parent.Name);

            int oid = GetNodeObjectId(e.Node);
            IRow tempRow = relatedTable.GetRow(oid);

            IGeometry geom = null;

            if (tempRow is IFeature)
            {
                IFeature feat = tempRow as IFeature;

                geom = feat.ShapeCopy;
                ISpatialReference srCopy = ((IClone)geom.SpatialReference).Clone() as ISpatialReference;

                IEnvelope envelope = new EnvelopeClass();
                envelope.SpatialReference = srCopy;
                envelope.Union(geom.Envelope);
                envelope.Expand(.25, .25, false);

                // crash here
                IMxDocument document = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
                IActiveView view = document.ActiveView;
                view.Extent = envelope;
            }
            else
                return;

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(relatedTable);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
```

Comment: what happens if you cast IMxDocument.FocusMap as IActiveView?

Comment: I would try breaking your statement into two statements to determine whether it is the cast to IMxDocument or accessing the ActiveView property that is throwing the exception.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and both failed :(.

Comment: I suspect the LoaderLock exception only happens when you are within a VS debugging session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code is executing in an event handler, it may be that you are making calls to ArcObjects on a separate thread. Take a look at ESRI's documentation for [writing multithreaded ArcObjects code](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000100000000), specifically the section **Calling ArcObjects from a thread other than the main thread**.

Comment: This could be it. I've had other problems with that before. What should it do? Just place the entire method separetly and call it from within the event?

Comment: I ran a quick test (version 9.3.1) and verified that this is not the issue. Perhaps it would help to post the rest of the code for your class that implements IDockableWindowDef.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the rest of the code. What I can tell you is that I load all my TreeNode objects using a cursor, which later is released. My tag object (of each node is the OID) and each category holds a table name.